# Why is sum of a sequence $\displaystyle s_n = \frac{n}{2}(a_1+a_n)$?

Tags: summation, arithmetic-progressions

Is there a way to prove that the sum of the arithmetic progression $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ can be calculated by $\displaystyle s_n = \frac{n}{2}(a_1+a_n)$?

Comment: You should edit your question such that it is clear what you are talking about. Also, mention why you want us to answer the given question, and spend at least a few minutes analysing it yourself, to see if it is complicated enough to request help.

Comment: To add on Beni's comment, you should know that there are *many many many* types of sequences, and you're referring only a specific type of sequences.

Comment: ....and more specifically.  This identity is true if the sequence is _arithmetic_.  It's not true of most sequences.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, providing this is an [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), so the change between each term is constant.

I find this chart sufficient to make the point

[image]

Comment: I love these "proof without words" pictures.

Comment: @anon no i dont like this at all. i dont get it and it makes me angry

Answer (score 11):

Use [Gauss's grade school trick.](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506134117/http://www.math.ucdenver.edu/%7Ejloats/gaussarticle.pdf) Sum this array in two different ways, row-first and column-first.

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_{n-1} & a_n \\\
a_n & a_{n-1} & \cdots & a_2 & a_1 
\end{array} $$

Row-first sum $ = 2\:\! s_n.\ $ Column-first sum $ =  n\ (a_1+a_n)\ $ since each column sum is constant (by hypothesis $\ a_{i+1}-a_i\: =\: a_j - a_{j-1}\:$ so $\  a_{i+1} + a_{j-1}\: =\:a_i + a_j).\:$ Thus  $\:s_n = n\:(a_1+a_n)/2.\:$ Transposing the above array yields the following graphical representation (for the case $\: n = 6)\,$ which is frequently presented as a "visual proof". Below I show it's essentially the same as above.

$$\begin{align} &a_1\ \ \color{blue}{\boxed{\qquad\color{black}{\phantom{a_n}\!}\qquad }}\color{red}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\qquad\color{black}{\phantom{a_n}}\qquad }}\ \ a_6\\  
&a_2\ \ \color{blue}{\boxed{\qquad\color{black}{\phantom{a_n}}\!\qquad }}\color{blue}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\qquad\color{black}{\phantom{a_n}}\qquad }}\ \ a_5\\  
&a_3\ \ \color{blue}{\boxed{\qquad\color{black}{\phantom{a_n}}\!\qquad }}\color{blue}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{blue}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\qquad\color{black}{\phantom{a_n}}\qquad }}\ \ a_4\\ 
& a_4\ \ \color{blue}{\boxed{\qquad\color{black}{\phantom{a_n}}\!\qquad }}\color{blue}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{blue}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{blue}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\qquad\color{black}{\phantom{a_n}}\qquad }}\ \ a_3\\  
& a_5\ \ \color{blue}{\boxed{\qquad\color{black}{\phantom{a_n}}\!\qquad }}\color{blue}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{blue}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{blue}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{blue}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\qquad\color{black}{\phantom{a_n}}\qquad }}\ \ a_2\\  
& a_6\ \ \color{blue}{\boxed{\qquad\color{black}{\phantom{a_n}}\!\qquad }}\color{blue}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{blue}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{blue}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{blue}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{blue}{\boxed{\phantom{\ a_n}}}\color{red}{\boxed{\qquad\color{black}{\phantom{a_n}}\qquad }}\ \ a_1
\end{align}$$

We calculate the area $A$ of the rectangle in two different ways. Assuming the rectangles are $1$ unit high, then $\,A = 2\:\!s_6\,$ where $\:s_6 = a_1+\:\cdots\:+a_6\:$ is the area of the entire blue figure - which is equal to its red reflection. On the other hand, the rectangle has height $\,6\,$ and width $\:a_1+a_6\:$ so $\:A = 6\,(a_1+a_6).\:$ That the rows have constant width follows from the fact that, by hypothesis, the squares  have constant width $\:w = a_{i+1}-a_i\:$ for all $\,i.\:$ So the operation that changes a row to that below, by changing the first red square to be blue, does not alter row width, since it amounts to subtracting $\,w\,$ from the red length $\,\color{red}r\,$ and adding it to the blue length $\,\color{blue}b,\,$ which preserves their sum since $\,\color{blue}{b+w}\color{red}{-w+r}\, =\, \color{blue}{b}+\color{red}{r.}\,$ Thus this "visual proof" - when made rigorous - amounts to precisely the same purely algebraic proof given above.

This trick of pairing up reflections around the average value is a special case of exploiting innate symmetry - here a reflection or involution. It's a ubiquitous powerful technique, e.g. see these posts on [Wilson's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865) and its [group theoretic generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9311/product-of-all-elements-in-an-odd-finite-abelian-group-is-1/9345#9345).

You can find analogous visual proofs, similar to assembling puzzle pieces, in Conway and Guy's [The Book of Numbers,](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/038797993X) e.g. the following one about triangular numbers.

$\qquad\qquad\quad$[image: triangular numbers diagram]
Striking puzzle-inspired proofs also occur in combinatorial group theory, where one assembles relators like puzzle pieces to obtain a proof that some word $= 1\:.\:$ For references see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26131/visual-representation-of-groups/26133#26133) on  Cayley graphs and Schreier coset graphs.

**Remark** $\ $ Here is another simple example from this [now deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1229221/242)

How to prove that the number $$1^{2015}+2^{2015}+3^{2015}+\cdots+2015^{2015}$$ is divisible by $2015$.

**Hint** $ $ If $\,f(x)\,$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients that is odd, i.e. $\,f(-x) = -f(x),\,$ e.g. $\,f(x) = x^{2015},\,$ then $\,f(n)+f(-n) = 0,\,$ so applying the above Gauss / Wilson reflection

$$\begin{align}{\rm mod}\,\ 2k\!+\!1\!:\ \  \color{#c00}{2k\equiv -1}&,\ \color{#0a0}{2k\!-\!1\equiv -2},\ldots,\ \ \ \color{#a0f}{k\!+\!1\equiv -k}\\[4px]
\Longrightarrow\qquad\ \ \ f(1)&\ \ \,+\,\ \ f(2)\  + \cdots + f(k)\\
 +\ f(\color{#c00}{2k})&\!+\!f(\color{#0a0}{2k\!-\!1})+\cdots+f(\color{#a0f}{k\!+\!1})\\[4px]
\equiv\ \ \ \quad f(1)&\ \ \,+\,\ \ f(2)\  + \cdots + f(k)\\
+\ f(\color{#c00}{-1})&\ +\ f(\color{#0a0}{-2})\ +\cdots+f(\color{#a0f}{-k})\\[4px]
\equiv\ \ \ \quad\ \color{#c00}0\quad & \ +\quad  \color{#0a0}0\quad\ \  + \cdots +\ \ \  \color{#a0f}0 
\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

**Note** $ $ Inserting into the sum the term $\,f(0) = 0\,$ then the sum is over the complete system of residues $\, 0,1,2\ldots {2k},\,$ and the reflection method amounts to replacing this by the *symmetric* system $\, -k,\ldots,-1,0,1,\ldots, k,\,$ where the reflection about the midpoint $\,0\,$ is given simply negation $\, n \mapsto -n \pmod{2k\!+\!1}.\,$ Such reflection (involution) symmetry is ubiquitous, e.g. at the heart of [Wilson's theorem in its various forms.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+wilson%27s+involution)

Above we used standard congruence arithmetic rules, esp. the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\, A\equiv a\,\Rightarrow\,f(A)\equiv f(a)\,$ for any polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ with integer coefficients. In your case we have that $\,f(x) = x^{2015},\,$ which is odd, so the Hint applies.

Comment: "Gauss's grade school trick" link isn't working

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Updated it, thanks.

Comment: You mentioned Wilson’s ubiquitous involution symmetry more than once here

Comment: @J.W.T The Remark quotes another (deleted) answer. I didn't edit it to remove any redundancy.

Answer (score 3):

This is valid only for arithmetical progressions, i.e. for sequences $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}$ with the property that $a_{n+1}=a_n+r,\ \forall n \geq 0$, where $r$ is a real constant.

To prove this for an arithmetic progression, you proceed as follows:
$$a_1+...+a_n=a_0+r+...+a_0+nr=na_0+r\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n}{2}(2a_0+(n+1)r)=\frac{n}{2}(a_1+a_n).$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain what you mean here, but I'll give an answer based on my interpertation of your question.

$$S_n=(a_1+d(0))+(a_1+d(1))+(a_1+d(2))+...+(a_1+d(n-1))+(a_1+d(n))$$

Now, $S_n$ can be rewritten in terms of $a_n$ (i.e. $a_1+d(n)$):

$$S_n=(a_n-(n)d)+(a_n-(n-1)d)+...+(a_n-(2)d)+(a_n-(1)d)+(a_n) \Rightarrow 2S_n=n(a_1+a_n) \Rightarrow S_n=\frac {n}{2}(a_1+a_n)$$