# The sum of all two digit numbers each of which leaves remainder 3 when divided by 5 is

Tags: number-theory

> The sum of all two digit numbers each of which leaves remainder 3 when divided by 5 is

Please solve it without without using arithmetic progression.
I have solved it by arithmetic progression and got the answer but I have to solve it by some other method?

Comment: I don't see any obvious way without using that the set of numbers are numbers of the form $5k+3$ for $k=2$ to $19.$ Using $j=k-2$, this is $5j+13$ for $j=0$ to $17.$ Then you have  the sum is $$\sum_{k=0}^{17}(5k+13)=18\cdot 13 + 5\cdot \frac{17\cdot 18}{2}$$

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by solving it "using arithmetic progressions." Can you show us your solution if you are seeking another?

Comment: Yeah sure, first of all I supposed that let the number be 5q+3 then I found that after putting q = 2 I got 13 as my first number and 18 as second and 23 as third number and also 96 as my greatest two digit number which follow this rule. After that I found that it's an arithmetic progression as a = 13 and common difference = 5 and we know that the sum of n term of arithmetic progression is n÷2(a+l) by using this I got my sum as 999.

Comment: But this question is of chapter real numbers in my book so I have to use the formulas including the chapter real numbers only. So I thought of asking this question as I am not getting any way out from real numbers.

Comment: We don't know what is in the chapter, so we can't say what is in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a shortcut to calculate the sum:

- We know the first term in the list (13) and the last term (98). There are 18 terms in total (= (98-13)/5 + 1)
- If you pair up the first term and the last term, and the second term and the second-to-last-term, etc. the pairs all have the same sum, 111.
- So we have 9 pairs of numbers that sum to 111. Their total is 999.

Comment: This way Is better.thanks.

Comment: @AnkitKumar This is [Gauss's grade school trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/44964/242) which is probably the most common way to sum an arithmetic progression.

Comment: @AnkitKumar This is the method I've seen used to prove the formula of the sum of an arithmetic sequence. It's also used in the derivation in Wikipedia's [Arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

Comment: I know buy rather ot does not connect by using some specific words of arithmetic progression. So it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

The sum is $$\sum _2^{19} ( 5k+3) = 5\sum _2^{19} ( k) + 3(18) = 5(189)+54 =999$$

Note that $$\sum _2^{19} k =\sum _1^{19} k -1 = \frac {19(20)}{2} -1=189$$

Comment: I am in class 10 we have not studied it yet.

Answer (score 0):

The first number is 13 and the last number is 98.   13+98 = 111.

The second number is 18 and the second last number is 93.  18+93 = 111.

How many 111's will there be?