# How to apply direct proof here?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

**Prove that the sum of five consecutive even numbers is divisible by five.**

I know this can be proved easily using proof by examples but, the instructions forbid us from doing so. I was thinking of applying direct proofs but have no idea as to how to go about it.

Edit: Is there any way to prove the statement?

Comment: Say the first even number is $n$. What is the rest of the numbers, and what is their sum?

Comment: No, it cannot be proved by examples. You can check that it’s true for some finite collection of examples, but that provides no guarantee that it is true for **all* examples.

Comment: If you do the calculation player3236 suggests it's actually a bit nicer to label $n$ the number in the middle, so the five consecutive numbers are $n-4, n-2, n, n+2, n+4$.

Comment: Re: prior comment, there are [nice symmetry-inspired ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/44964/242) to compute such sums, going back to Gauss's grade school summation trick and continuing with proofs of Wilson's theorem, etc.  Note: with $k = n/2\,$ the sum is twice the sum of $\, k-2,\, k-1,\, k,\, k+1,\, k+2,\,$ i.e. $5$ consecutive integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asked to prove for even numbers, so start with an even number $n$.

The next four consecutive even numbers are $n+2$, $n+4$, $n+6$, and $n+8$.

The sum of these numbers is $5n+20 = 5(n+4)$.

Since the sum is an integer times $5$, the sum is divisible by $5$, and you're done.

As a bonus, $n$ can be odd also!